# Appcelerator Windows Phone 10 - Problems with views

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

As I understand the support for Windows Phone 10 is not 100% yet, but this is very basic and should work?

I can get the app running, but I can not see views that are added on top of other views. It seems it can only show one view at the time.

Also, the "swipe" eventlistener is not doing anything.

Has anyone made a Win Phone 10 app work properly by using Appcelerator?

My app project is pretty large, but running fine on other platforms. I am using Classic, not Alloy.